# What is the proper pattern for instantiating and showing a window that relies on a value selected in the current window?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Using dependency injection principles and a DI container, what is the proper pattern to launch a child dialog that requires a selection made in the parent window as a dependency? Example: Select a PersonViewModel in a list on the main window, and click a button to launch the Details window. The Details window needs a PersonViewModel passed to it to provide the DataContext.

The two methods that I've found:

1. Pass in the child window as a dependency and use property injection to provide the child window dependency before calling ShowDialog.
2. Pass in a ViewFactory which is used to resolve the child window and use property injection to provide the child window dependency before calling ShowDialog.

What I'm looking for is a generally accepted testable pattern. All the examples of DI that I find seem to be only one layer deep or don't require a dependency selected in the parent window.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you working with WPF ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I tagged this WPF but forgot to mention in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a different method. The way that I'd recommend doing this is to create a small manager object for displaying the dialog window, through which you can pass parameters to the dialog window's view-model before it's used to create the window itself.

Create factories for your window and view-model, and use them something like this:

```
public class DetailsWindowDisplayer : IDetailsWindowDisplayer
{
    private readonly IDetailsWindowFactory windowFactory;
    private readonly IDetailsWindowViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;

    public DetailsWindowDisplayer(
        IDetailsWindowFactory windowFactory,
        IDetailsWindowViewModelFactory viewModelFactory)
    {
        this.windowFactory = windowFactory;
        this.viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;
    }

    public void ShowDetails(IPersonViewModel personViewModel)
    {
        var windowViewModel = this.viewModelFactory.Create(personViewModel);
        var window = this.windowFactory.Create(windowViewModel);
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Then it's a simple case of injecting `IDetailsWindowDisplayer` into the parent view-model, and calling the `ShowDetails` method. This abstracts the showing of the dialog to a single call, and the `DetailsWindowDisplayer` has only a single responsibility.

To make it completely testable, your window factory should return an interface. You can do this with the following hierarchy:

```
public interface IDialogWindow
{
    void Show();
}

public interface IDetailsWindow : IDialogWindow
{
}

public class DetailsWindow : Window, IDetailsWindow
{
    // The Show() method from IDialogWindow is automatically implemented
    // by the WPF Window class
}
```

If you prefer to keep your details window as a singleton, you can inject the window into the constructor of `DetailsWindowDisplayer` and either 1. set a new view-model on it each time it's shown, or 2. make its view-model a singleton too, put a `ViewModel` property on to the window and a `Person` property on to the view-model, and then set `Person` to be the new `PersonViewModel` instance each time.

Answer (score 0):

In general I tend not to use the container for resolution of the Views.
There are several projects which are specialized for making View-ViewModel bindings in a very good way.

I suggest that you checkout on Caliburn.Micro, for the UI stuff and use the container for all othere dependency injection. If you need any help with setting up Caliburn.Micro with Windsor, please let me know.